# Mule - remove first row from csv file

Tags: csv, mule, mule-studio, splitter

I'm using Mule CE and need to remove the first row (containing headers) of an incoming CSV file so that I can pass it to a transformer to be converted to maps. How would I achieve this? My guess would be some kind of splitter, but I've not had any luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jdbc:csv-to-maps-transformer contains a property ignoreFirstRecord, but if you have your csv transformations done with some custom transformer, you may have to do this with Java (or some of the scripting languages). I don't think there is any standard Mule component that does this out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks @Anton - the csv-to-maps-transformer was my first choice however we're limited to using Mule CE! I'll have a look into passing it through a custom Java component. Thanks for your response.